# how to install Qt5 in linux (mandriva2010)

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I downloaded Qt 5 under Linux both 64bit and 32bit and the extension was *.run. I tried all these and it just doesn't work.

sh qt_linux.run

this error:  qt_linux.run: qt_linux.run: cannot execute binary file

or

chmod +x qt_linux.run
./qt_linux.run

this error:  ./qt_linux.run: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by ./qt_linux.run)

or

```
* double click it
```

this error:  nothing happens

or

```
* right click it>properties
* check the box next to executable
* double click it
```

this error:  nothing happens

Comment: yes, didn't saw it, dublicate indeed

Answer (score 1):

It says, that you don't have glibc installed. Try `sudo apt-get install build-essential`
and try to install it again - `chmod u+x qt-linux-opensource-5.0.1-x86-offline.run`

If not helps - try to follow some of the install guides, for example, like this one - http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/25260